# Lemma for proving existence of infinitely many primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This problem is from Gerstein's *Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs*. Part b of the problem is to give a particular kind of proof that there are inifinitely many primes. I am concerned with part a, the required lemma. Part a is stated:

Show that if $n \ge 3$ then there is a prime number p satisfying $n \lt p \le n!-1$.

There is a hint:

"Consider a prime divisor p of $(n-1)!-1$. Why does p exist?"

Here is my attempt at a solution:

p exists because every integer has a prime divisor. For the k-th prime $p_k$, define

$p_k!!=\Pi_{i=1}^{k} p_i$ where $p_i$ is the i-th prime.

The symbol p denotes a prime divisor of $(n-1)!-1$. My conjecture is that  $p!!+1$ is prime. We only need to show that it is in the required range.

It is reasonable (though I have not proved it) to suppose that $p!!+1 > n$.

$p!!$ is the product of fewer than n integers, each of which is less than or equal to p, which than or equal to n. So $p!!+1\le n!-1$ and the purported proof, such as it is, would be complete.

Is there any merit to this argument? If not, how can the proposition be demonstrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$13!!+1=30031=59\cdot509$ is not prime, so the argument cannot work.

However, it is certainly true that $n!-1$ has a prime divisor $p$, and clearly $p\le n!-1$, so we need only show that $p>n$. Since $p\mid n!-1$, clearly $p\not\mid n!$; but every positive integer $\le n$ divides $n!$, so $p$ cannot be $\le n$. Thus, we must have $n<p\le n!-1$.